# How can a closure using the `move` keyword create a FnMut closure?

Tags: rust

Up to this moment I thought that `move |...| {...}` would move variables inside a closure and the closure would implement only `FnOnce`, because you can move variables only once. To my surprise, however, I found that this code works:

```
extern crate futures;

use futures::stream;
use futures::stream::{Stream, StreamExt};
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo(i32);

fn bar(r: Rc<Foo>) -> Box<Stream<Item = (), Error = ()> + 'static> {
    Box::new(stream::repeat::<_, ()>(()).map(move |_| {
        println!("{:?}", r);
    }))
}

fn main() {
    let r = Rc::new(Foo(0));
    let _ = bar(r);
}
```

Despite `map` having this signature:

```
fn map<U, F>(self, f: F) -> Map<Self, F>
where
    F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> U,
```

It's surprising to me that a `FnMut` closure was created when using the `move` keyword and it even has `'static` lifetime. Where can I find some details about `move`? Or how does it actually work?

Comment: Relevant book sections: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch13-01-closures.html#capturing-the-environment-with-closures and https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch16-01-threads.html#using-move-closures-with-threads

Comment: The important distinction here is that `move` causes the variables to be _moved into_ the closure at creation time, which does not prevent the closure from being called more than once.  If the closure code moves any value _out of the captured variables_, i.e. consumes these values, the closure becomes `FnOnce`.  You can only move values out of captured variables if they are first moved into the closure, but just moving the values in by itself does not make the closure `FnOnce`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this point is quite confusing, and I think the wording of the Rust book contributes. After I read it, I thought the same as you did: that a `move` closure was necessarily `FnOnce`, and that a non-`move` closure was `FnMut` (and may also be `Fn`). But this is kind-of backwards from the real situation.

The closure can capture values from the scope where it's created. `move` controls how those values go into the closure: either by being moved, or by reference. But it's how they're used *after* they're captured that determines whether the closure is `FnMut` or not.

If the body of the closure consumes any value it captured, then the closure can only be `FnOnce`. After the closure runs the first time, and consumes that value, it can't run again.

As you've mentioned, you can consume a value inside the closure by calling `drop` on it, or in other ways, but the most common case is to return it from the closure, which moves it out of the closure. Here's the simplest example:

```
let s = String::from("hello world");
let my_fnonce = move || { s };
```

If the body of the closure doesn't consume any of its captures, then it's `FnMut`, whether it was `move` or not. If it also doesn't mutate any of its captures, it's also `Fn`; any closure that is `Fn` is also `FnMut`. Here's a simple example, albeit not a very good one.

```
let s = "hello world";
let my_fn = move || { s.len() }
```

### Summary

The `move` modifier controls how captures are moved **into** the closure when it's **created**. `FnMut` membership is determined by how captures are moved **out of** the closure (or consumed in some other way) when it's **executed**.

Comment: This is a much more complete answer. I'm going to have to include it in the [taken docs](https://github.com/vitiral/taken/issues/1)

Answer (score 4):

> Up to this moment I thought that `move |...| {...}` will move variables inside closure and closure will implement only `FnOnce`, because you can move vars only once.

The variables are moved when the closure is created, not when it is invoked. Since you're only creating one closure, the move only happens once - regardless of how often `map` calls the function.

Comment: I see, but still this topic leaves a lot of confusion for me. Examples - in TRPL:

    FnOnce consumes the variables it captures from its enclosing scope, known as the closure’s environment. To consume the captured variables, the closure must take ownership of these variables and move them into the closure when it is defined. The Once part of the name represents the fact that the closure can’t take ownership of the same variables more than once, so it can be called only once.

Comment: The other source: http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/05/finding-closure-in-rust/: Similarly, if closure was to be || drop(v);—that is, move out of v—it would be illegal to implement either Fn or FnMut. 


But this code run totally fine:
`
    let r = Some(1);
    let c: Box<Fn()> = Box::new(move || {
        drop(r);
    });
    c();
    c();
`

Comment: @AlexeyKarasev Regarding your first comment, this is exactly in line with this answer – also see my comment on the question.  Regarding your second comment, the example you gave is a bit misleading, since `Option<i32>` implements the `Copy` trait, so it's not actually consumed by `drop()`.  If you try with something that's not `Copy`, you will see an error for that code.

Comment: Oh, I see, so it looks like my understanding of wording was the trouble. So in TRPL by consume they mean smth like if let Some(x) = r inside closure. If something is moved inside the closure (like r in this case) they refer to it as capturing. So basically FnOnce means, that you're destroying Environment, that's why you can only call it once (the next call won't have the same Environment). Move on the other hand deals with having references to stack, so it's more like the lifetime issue.