# Are Fn() + 'static and FnMut() + 'static equivalent?

Tags: rust

I have what I think to be a simple question, but not much luck finding an answer for it.

#### Background

I understand the difference between `Fn` and `FnMut` in Rust, but I see quite often the need to accept closures that require a `'static` lifetime bound.

#### The Question

Is an `Fn() + 'static` equivalent to `FnMut() + 'static`?

#### My Opinion

In my opinion, I seem to believe they are, because an `Fn` allows for capturing immutable references to its environment, whereas `FnMut`, mutable references, however, due to the `'static` lifetime bound, the only references they can have, are owned ones, and therefore will almost always have move semantics associated with the closure. Since only owned values, or special `&'static` references can have `'static` lifetime, it seems to me pointless to want to have or need an `FnMut()` in this case, since there is no mutable reference one might be able to get to the closures environment.

Am I wrong with this conclusion? My guess is yes, otherwise there would probably be a Clippy lint for this.

Comment: I think you're wrong. `FnMut` can mutate the values it *captures*, which `Fn` can't. Yes, both typically own the captured values (although they can refer to static borrowed data as well), but the latter means that you can invoke `Fn` from multiple threads (if it's also `Sync`), which you can't do with `FnMut`.

Comment: To illustrate @user4815162342's point, this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f212056698fba0fe420aff9d672357e1) shows the difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a closure using the `move` keyword create a FnMut closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50135871/3650362)

Comment: Also possibly relevant: [When does a closure implement Fn, FnMut and FnOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30177395/3650362) and [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40053550/3650362) (the `'static` bound here does not mean "contains some `&'static` reference")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any closure type can capture any kind of data. The difference is how the closure can access the captured data while it is executed. An `Fn` closure receives a shared reference to its captured data. An `FnMut` closure receives a mutable reference to its captured data, so it can mutate it. And finally, an `FnOnce` closure receives ownership of the captrued data, which is why you can call it only once.

The `'static` trait bound means that the captured data has static lifetime. This is completely orthogonal to the question what a closure can do with its captured data while it is called.